# How to cache websites in UIWebView correctly?

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview

I have a `UISwitch` and if it's active my `UIWebView` should cache all visited websites.

If it's active I have the following code

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:32 * 1024 * 1024];
[self setRequestObj:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:loadUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60.0]];
```

If I deactivated my `UISwitch` my code do something like this

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
[self setRequestObj:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:loadUrl]];
```

Is there some method I have to activated it works correctly? If it's switched off it should load everything from the web server at every call. If it's switched on it should load everything from his cache if he has visited it before.

If I close the app and open it again and my `Button` is still switched to on it seems there is no cache although I didn't delete it if I close my app.

Sry if it's complicated to understand ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
   // Determile cache file path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"index.html"];   

// Download and write to file
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.uk"];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

// Load file in UIWebView
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609635/ios-cache-a-uiwebview) for more details.

hope this will help :)