# How to enable caching in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

how I can enable caching in an `UIWebView`?

It's frustrating. I'm looking for hours but no mentioned solutions in many other posts doesn't helped me.

I tried many solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/26174438, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424301, http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/CachePolicies.html, [iOS Cache a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609635/ios-cache-a-uiwebview), etc.

My code looks like

```
    [self setUrl:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://example.com"]];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
    [self setLoadUrl: [NSURL URLWithString:[self url]]];
    [self setRequestObj:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self loadUrl]]];
```

if `caching`is disabled. If it's turned on I have

```
if([[self cache] isEqualToNumber:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1]])
{
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:32 * 1024 * 1024];
    [self setRequestObj:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:loadUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0]];
}
```

How

Comment: Can you try this url https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300 and tell me the results.

Comment: Try this answer and implement NSMutableURLRequest http://stackoverflow.com/a/26174438/3116236

Comment: @iSashok I tried this answer too and it's also linked at my post. Doesn't helped me ... What did I wrong?

Comment: @iSashok Do I have implement something else? I tried it too and `[[self webView] loadRequest:[self request]];` is my NSMutableURLRequest

Comment: [I think you missed this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16830262/1066828)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Premox I think you can choose a different way. After your uiwebview loaded page you can get a response html convert to NSString class and save it to cache or serialize as you wanna